# Please give me the rewrite rules for my ugly urls

Tags: url-rewriting, functions, urls, mod-rewrite

In functions.php I am adding a rewrite rule for this url:

http://www.myblog.com/?currentpage=1 
http://www.myblog.com/?currentpage=2 
And so on...

This is the code I use, can u please give me the rewrite rules to transform my urls into pretty ones?

```
    add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' ); 
    function wpa5413_init() {     
        // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!     
        add_rewrite_rule(           
            'Please add my rewrite rule',         
            'Please add my rewrite rule',  
            'top' ); 
    }

    add_filter('query_vars', 'wpa3537_query_vars'); 
    function wpa3537_query_vars($query_vars) {     
        $query_vars[] = 'currentpage';     
        return $query_vars;
    }
```

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to get

- http://www.myblog.com/currentpage/1
- http://www.myblog.com/currentpage/2

then your function should be

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'currentpage_rewrite_rule_222');

function currentpage_rewrite_rule_222($wp_rewrite){
  $newrules = array();
  $new_rules['currentpage/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?currentpage=$matches[1]';
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

and just keep your query_vars function the way it is.

```
 add_filter('query_vars', 'wpa3537_query_vars'); 
    function wpa3537_query_vars($query_vars) {     
        $query_vars[] = 'currentpage';     
        return $query_vars;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I use a plugin to analyze my rewrite, it's active but not working, any ideeas?:(

Comment: By the way, currentpage1, currentpage2 are from a custom pagination script - i pull data from an external table and paginate them on idex.php

Comment: idex.php or index.php? and what do you get from that plugin when analyzing?

Comment: Patternt is currentpage/(d*)$ and Substitution is currentpage: (d*) . Index.php is the blog normal index and i have http://blog.mysite.com/index.php?currentpage=1

Comment: @webmasters: you are not using wordpress, see: http://blog.mysite.com/index.php - it gives a 404.